# Display ePub Files Using Flutter

Tags: flutter, epub

Having solely developed Android applications I have decided to try crossplatform development, so far Flutter has been a much more pleasant experience than Xamarin however, I have now run into a roadblock.

I want to give users the ability to read ePub files downloaded from my server. I came across this Flutter package but it is not clear to me how to display the ePub inside a container to the user - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/epub

I cannot find any examples/tutorials other than the one provided on the example page (which has a Image package conflict. I fixed this conflict by changing the package import line to `'import package:image/image.dart' as image`) then all references to it in the main method to `image.Image`. This might be another issue to resolve another day when it comes to adding custom placeholders for missing images.

I cannot share my ePub files but I have tested with the one found on the github repository here https://github.com/orthros/dart-epub/blob/dev/test/hittelOnGoldMines.epub

Thank you

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @SameerDonga no never did, we changed to using PDF

Comment: have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/epub_view ?

Answer (score 0):

The only resource that I found was https://github.com/pycampers/flutter_pdf_viewer, but for now it is just for Android.

Another aproach is to load a webview and load the pdf using some JS framework.

Comment: The ePub files I have when extracted are html pages, so a webview might be the route to take. Thanks